# Adding more folders for deployment with phpStorm

Tags: file, ftp, save, phpstorm

I already added additional folders from the same FTP via `View > Remote Host`. As I press sync the new folders doesn't appear in my local copy or in the project view. Now I like to have the local copy that I can edit (autosync on save is enabled).

How do I import those additional files?

Comment: Did you try this already: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/comparing-deployed-files-and-folders-with-their-local-versions.html#procedure%0A____________synchronize_foldersto_synchronize_the_contents_of_folderssynchronizing_contents_of_folders? **Synchronizing contents of folders**.

Comment: Yee, there are just files recommended that were changed by others.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it.  From the Remote Host tab right-click the folder and select "Remove Path From Excluded".  Then I drag the remote folder over to where it should be in the Project (local) pane and it copies all the files over.

I tried the sync from deployed, sync with local like the docs say but never did anything.  Above method worked for me